# Union all imported types

Tags: typescript

Is there way to union all imported types from module?
Like this

```
import * as types from "./types";

type Union_ = Union<types> // type1 | type2 | ...
```

I also know that only types and interfaces will be exported from this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.
You have to do named imports.
One possible solution is to union all the types in your `types.ts` file and export it from there and use it in this file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question:
[Is there a good way to generate types by importing all variables from a file in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130870/is-there-a-good-way-to-generate-types-by-importing-all-variables-from-a-file-in)

There are a couple of ways that you *can* do this, but ideally you'd avoid wildcard imports in anything that will be bundled into your build.

What I ended up not going with:

```js
import * as types from './types';

const typeValues = Object.values(types);
export type FooConst = typeValues[number];
```

The other idea I was working on would involve compilation to generate a union type based on the imports. something like [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)