# Is there a good way to generate types by importing all variables from a file in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have a file with a lot of constant variables in it:

```js
// foo.ts
export const FOO = 'foo';
export const BAR = 'bar';
```

I want to be able to declare a type that enforces that a `value` is one of those constants:

```js
// fooTypes.ts
import * as consts from './foo';

const fooObjects = Object.values(consts);  // I don't want to declare this variable
export type FooConst = fooObjects[number]; // type ActivityType = "foo" | "bar"
```

This does what I want, `FooConsts` contains a union of all of the values from foo.ts, but **I don't want to have to declare additional variables that will end up in my run-time/bundle**. This is just for type checking.

```js
// useFooTypes.ts
import { FooConst } from './fooTypes'

type FooHolder {
  value: FooConst;
}
```

Also, I don't want to repeat all those declarations in a union type.

I tried doing this in a declaration file, but alas, `Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.ts(1036)`

Comment: Your code and comments are mismatching, please recheck

Comment: Looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263200/how-to-define-string-literal-union-type-from-constants-in-typescript ?

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you want a TypeScript [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching my implementation to use [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

```js
// foo.js
export type Foo = keyof typeof foo;

export enum foo {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar'
}
```